# To get number of employees working in a Department

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Creating Department table

```
CREATE TABLE department
( DEPARTMENT_ID         NUMBER(4)       PRIMARY KEY,    
  DEPARTMENT_NAME   VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ADDRESS           VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL);
```

Populating Department Table

```
INSERT INTO department VALUES(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(40, 'IT', 'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(50, 'EXECUTIVE', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(60, 'MARKETING', 'CHICAGO');
COMMIT;
```

Creating Employee table

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
( EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER(4)       PRIMARY KEY,
  EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
  JOB           VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
  MANAGER_ID    NUMBER(4),
  HIRE_DATE     DATE            NOT NULL,
  SALARY        NUMBER(9, 2)    NOT NULL,
  COMMISSION    NUMBER(9, 2),
  DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) REFERENCES department(DEPARTMENT_ID));
```

Populating Employee table

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7839, 'KING',  'PRESIDENT', NULL, '20-NOV-01', 5000, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7596, 'JOST',  'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '04-MAY-01', 4500, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7603, 'CLARK', 'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '12-JUN-01', 4000, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7566, 'JONES', 'PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT', 7596, '05-APR-01', 3000, NULL,     10);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7886, 'STEEL', 'PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT', 7566, '08-MAR-03', 2500, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7610, 'WILSON', 'ANALYST', 7596, '03-DEC-01', 3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7999, 'WOLFE',  'ANALYST', 7610, '15-FEB-02', 2500, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7944, 'LEE', 'ANALYST', 7610, '04-SEP-06', 2400, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7900, 'FISHER', 'SALESMAN', 7603, '06-DEC-01', 3000, 500, 30);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7921, 'JACKSON', 'SALESMAN', 7900, '25-FEB-05', 2500, 400, 30);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7952, 'LANCASTER', 'SALESMAN',  7900, '06-DEC-06', 2000, 150, 30);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7910, 'SMITH', 'DATABASE ADMINISTRATOR', 7596, '20-DEC-01', 2900,     NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7788, 'SCOTT', 'PROGRAMMER', 7910, '15-JAN-03', 2500, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7876, 'ADAMS', 'PROGRAMMER', 7910, '15-JAN-03', 2000, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7934, 'MILLER','PROGRAMMER', 7876, '25-JAN-02', 1000, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(8000, 'BREWSTER',  'TBA',  NULL,   '22-AUG-13', 2500, NULL, NULL);
COMMIT;
```

**QUESTION:** Based on the DEPARTMENT and EMPLOYEE tables created in write a PL/SQL anonymous block that accepts an employee ID from the user input and displays 1) the employee’s name, hire date, and total pay (salary + commission), 2) his/her manager’s name, hire date, and total pay (salary + commission), 3) the name of the department where the employee works, 4) the number of employees in the department where the employee works, and 5) the sum of total pay (salary + commission) for the department where the employee works,

So far I've got the query below I am not able to get the number of employees working in the department. How can I do that?

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the employee id:'

DECLARE
v_input_emp_id NUMBER := &p_1;
v_emp_name employee.employee_name%TYPE;
v_dept_name department.department_name%TYPE;
v_pay employee.salary%TYPE;
v_n NUMBER;
v_output VARCHAR2(100) := 'The employee id is not in the table';
v_hiredate EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_n
FROM employee
WHERE employee_id = v_input_emp_id;

IF v_n = 0 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_input_emp_id || ' is not in the EMPLOYEE table.');
END IF;

IF v_n = 1 THEN

SELECT employee_name, salary + NVL(commission, 0),HIRE_DATE
INTO v_emp_name, v_pay, v_hiredate
FROM employee
WHERE employee_id = v_input_emp_id;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER INPUT:');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_input_emp_id);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------EMPLOYEE----------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('NAME:',10,' ') || lpad(v_emp_name,15));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('HIRE DATE:',10) || lpad(v_hiredate,20));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL PAY:' || lpad(TO_CHAR(ROUND(v_pay, 2),
'$9,990.00'),21));

IF v_input_emp_id IS NOT NULL THEN

SELECT manager_id
INTO v_MANAGER_ID
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE employee_id = v_input_emp_id;

SELECT employee_name, salary + NVL(commission, 0),HIRE_DATE
INTO v_emp_name, v_pay, v_hiredate
FROM employee
WHERE v_manager_id = employee_id;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------MANAGER----------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('NAME:',10,' ') || lpad(v_emp_name,15));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('HIRE DATE:',10) || lpad(v_hiredate,20));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL PAY:' || lpad(TO_CHAR(ROUND(v_pay, 2),
'$9,990.00'),21));

ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NO DATA');

END IF;

IF v_n = 1 THEN

SELECT  department_name
INTO        v_dept_name
FROM        department
INNER JOIN  employee
ON      department.department_id = employee.department_id 
WHERE       employee_id = v_input_emp_id;

/*
SELECT department_id
INTO v_dept_id
from department 
WHERE department_id = v_dept_id;

SELECT  COUNT(*)
INTO        v_emp_num
FROM        employee INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT
ON DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE       employee.department_id = department.v_dept_id;
*/

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------DEPARTMENT----------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || v_dept_name);
/*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES' || ' ' || TO_CHAR(v_emp_num));  
  */  
        ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No output!');  

    END IF;

END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Blatantly an assignment. So rather than saying "it doesn't work", provide more details about exactly what is not working, errors you get, wrong results etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need simple query for departament, for example:

```
SELECT  department_name
, count(employee_id) over (partition by department_id) AS count_of_employee
, EMPLOYEE_NAME
, HIRE_DATE 
, SALARY + COMMISSION AS pay
, managers.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS manager
, sum(SALARY + COMMISSION) over (partition by department_id) AS total_pay
FROM department
INNER JOIN employee            ON department.department_id = employee.department_id
LEFT JOIN employee as managers ON managers.employee_id = employee.MANAGER_ID 
WHERE department_id = .........;
```

or for employee:

```
SELECT  department_name
, count_of_employee
, EMPLOYEE_NAME
, HIRE_DATE 
, SALARY + COMMISSION AS pay
, managers.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS manager
, total_pay
FROM employee       
INNER JOIN department          ON department.department_id = employee.department_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Count(1) AS count_of_employee
  , Sum(SALARY + COMMISSION) AS total_pay
  , department_id
  FROM employee
  GROUP BY department_id
  ) AS employee_total          ON employee_total.department_id = employee.department_id
LEFT JOIN employee as managers ON managers.employee_id  = employee.MANAGER_ID 
WHERE employee_id = v_input_emp_id;
```